# ARDAgent.app - what is it?

Tags: macos, firewall

I sign into a few different email accounts for different family members and I have a few. Im not sure if that is how it happened but What is ARDAgent.app? I found it as being allowed in my Security and Privacy in my firewall.

Answer (score 3):

ARDAgent is a faceless (no dock icon, no windows) helper application for Apple Remote Desktop.

ARDAgent is very useful for people who use Apple Remote Desktop to manage a large number of Macs; it can run programs on behalf of the remote administrator, for instance.